# custom uitableview cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i am using following : cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
so it shows ">" for all cell but i want it should not seen on 1st cell because it is head line for table

now its look like 
cell 1 ---Status 000>
     2 ---Detail1000>
     3 ---Detail200   >

but I need 
cell 1 ---Status 000>
     2 ---Detail1000>
     3 ---Detail200   >
0-as spaces
in short i dont need ">" on 1st cell in my table view as it dont have any detail view
thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath do this:

```
if ( indexPath.row == 0 )
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```